# Why kubectl is required to be installed on every node while setting up cluster using kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

According to kubernetes documentation here,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl

Setting up a Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm requires to install kubectl on all nodes. However, kubeserver-api is only installed on the master node or control plane with the command,

kubeadm init

My question is why do we need kubectl on the worker nodes?

Comment: That sounds like a "documentation bug," as searching the kubeadm source code did not reveal any usages that look like they're shelling out to kubectl -- have you tried just not installing kubectl on the workers?

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl` is a CLI for controling your cluster so you do not need to install it on the worker nodes. You have to install it in a place where you are going to manage your cluster from.

As stated in the comments by the community this indeed looks like a documentation error as there is no relation between `kubeadm` and `kubectl` when joining the nodes.  For worker nodes you just need to install both kubelet and kubeadm.

Comment: What is required to be installed on each node? i've read that kubelet at a minimum? is that a standable or part of a bigger installation required for each node?

Comment: @mike01010 kubeadm and kubelet. kuebeadm is for bootstrapping cluster and joining the workers to the master. kubelet is agent that runs on every node and handles comm with master etc.